# Prove that a linear map $A$ does not have an inverse map if $A \circ A$ = O where $A$ is a linear transformation from X onto itself

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My solution is this: Since $A$ maps from a finite dimension vector space onto the same space, if $A$ is injective it should also be surjective. If $A$ is injective then $A(A(x))$ should also be injective which is a contradiction since $A(A(x))$ is equal to the zero $(O)$ map. Hence $A$ is not injective implying it isn't surjective implying an inverse mapping cannot exist. Is this good enough or should I be rigorous in some other way?

Comment: You should say something about what $X$ is, as it is mentioned in the title but not in the body of the Question.  Perhaps it is the same as the "finite dimension vector space" mentioned there?  You would need to know $X$ has positive dimension to establish $A$ does not have an inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Violation in injectivity is apparent, which is sufficient proof in my opinion. Not that apparent, however, how you deduce that lack of injectivity implies it's not surjective.

Of course it should be shown rigorously that $A$ is not injective and that concludes the proof, because invertibility requires bijectivity. If there is no injectivity, then there is no bijectivity.

Comment: Yeah. I should prove that. Injection implies nullspace is trivial. Implying dimension of range is equal to dimension of vector space X (Rank Nullity Theorem) implying the range is equal to vector space X (isomorphism) implying the Linear map is surjective also. Right?

Comment: Also is the implication that A isn't injective if A compositite A isn't injective correct? Is that implication that I used in my proof correct?

Comment: Thanks. I will close this question.

Comment: Yes, $A$ injection implies $A\circ A$ is an injection.